# Remove from array with objects by id

Tags: javascript

**Agenda:**
I want to write a function that removes one index 
(preferably by `affiliationId` but by`index` of array is also ok) from an array of objects.

**This is my current array of objects**
[image: My array of objects]

```
    const deleteAndFilterAffiliations = (id:string, index:any) => {
     deleteAffiliation("/" + id) //imported function that makes a DELETE API call
     const updatedArray = value.splice(index, 1)
     setValue(updatedArray)
    }
```

The code above is how I'm doing it currently, but when I call this function it removes all objects except one, [0], from the array.

**How i call the function:**
`onClick={() => deleteAndFilterAffiliations(item.affiliationId, {index})}`

---

All suggestions on how i can improve this code/re-write it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use `Array.filter` - `let filteredArr = arr.filter(a => a.affiliationId !== affiliationId);`

Comment: Bottomside of any popular library/framework - people start ***using*** them ***before*** learning basics of JavaScript itself.

Comment: *'...All suggestions...much appreciated'* Here goes mine - take a closer look into official docs on [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to check up what exactly it is supposed to return. Chances are, while doing that you may come accross [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you use .filter() as others suggest.

that being said, the problem is that .splice() remove the section of the array and it returns the part of the array that you removed.

Example:

```
var letters = ["a", "b", "c"]
var removed = letters.splice(1, 1);
console.log(letters) // ["a", "c"]
console.log(removed) // ["b"]
```

the solution using .splice() is:

```
const deleteAndFilterAffiliations = (id:string, index:any) => {
    deleteAffiliation("/" + id) //imported function that makes a DELETE API call
    value.splice(index, 1)
    setValue(value)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, it adds a huge deal of value to the line in the very first comment under OP.

Answer (score -1):

Use like this

```
const deleteAndFilterAffiliations = (id) => {
     let filtered = value.filter(a=>a.affiliationId!==id);
     setValue(filtered)
    }
```

filter you array of objects by id and remove clicked object and then just update to state array.

Comment: Single line of code in the very first comment under OP is pretty much what this question is worth. Posting such answers (and, more importantly, upvoting them) turn this community into free ***'I wunt codz'***-service

Comment: ...and it wasn't my downvote, just in case, so, no need to rush downvoting my own posts ;)